# VBA Word Copy text from specific word till the end of the document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to copy text from specific word (Let's say it is **Specific Requirements**) till the end of the document.

I have prepared code which could potentially solve the issue but I don't know what has to be added to .text to make it work as I wish.

---

```
Sub Copying()
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Format = False
    .Forward = True
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Text = "Specific Requirements"
    .Execute
  End With
  If .Find.Found = True Then .Copy
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use Find, the active Range moves to the Found range. To extend that to the end of the document you need code like:

```
Sub Copying()
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Format = False
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .Text = "Specific Requirements"
    .Execute
  End With
  If .Find.Found = True Then
    .End = ActiveDocument.Range.End
    .Copy
  End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, the proposed solution is working perfectly